# ImageBackground component as a container of react-navigation router hiding all child components

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, expo, imagebackground

I want to set a background image to all of the screens in my react native application,

I am using ImageBackground component on the top level of my components tree like that:

```
export default class App extends React.Component {
render(){
 return(
    <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
        <ImageBackground source={require('../assets/app-bg.png')} style={{width: '100%', height: '100%', flex: 1, zIndex: 0, resizeMode: 'cover' }}>
            <Router />
        </ImageBackground>
    </View>)
}
}
```

and I have the child component which is the router from react-navigation
like that:

```
class LandingPage extends React.Component {
    render(){
return(
        <View style={{flex: 1, zIndex: 999}}>
        <Text>here is landing page></Text>
        </View>
      )
    }
  }

const RouterNavigator = createAppContainer(createStackNavigator({
    Landing: {
        screen: Landing,
        navigationOptions:{
            header: null
        }
    }
}

export default class Router extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return <RouterNavigator style={{flex: 1}}/>
    }
}
```

the problem is that the background image is being rendered but the child component LandingPage is being hidden even though it is being rendered too!

Comment: You don't need to enclose Imagebackground inside View tag.Remove View tag above and below ImageBackground tag .Hope removing View tag helps.

Comment: I didn't find any render method in App component.or if you haven't written proper code in your question please provide it correctly! otherwise, I have tried your example in expo it works fine.
https://snack.expo.io/@paraskorat/aGVhbH

Comment: @shrutigarg thanks but it didn't work

Comment: @ParasKorat the problem only happens when i try to put the ImageBackground before the RouterNavigator, if you try to put the router as a child it wont work.

Comment: why have  you used zIndex in Landing Page ?What is its purpose?

Comment: @shrutigarg I was just trying to see if can make a difference, but it does not affect anything

Answer (score 0):

```
Just have a look at this example.Does this help you acheive what you were 
trying to.

import * as React from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet, ImageBackground } from 'react-native';
import { Constants } from 'expo';

import AssetExample from './components/AssetExample';
import { createAppContainer, createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';

import { Card } from 'react-native-paper';

class LandingPage extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>here is landing page</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const RouterNavigator = createAppContainer(
  createStackNavigator(
    {
      LandingPage: {
        screen: LandingPage,
        navigationOptions: {
          header: null,
        },
      },
    },
    {
      mode: 'card',
      transparentCard: true,
      cardStyle: { backgroundColor: 'transparent' },
      transitionConfig: () => ({
        containerStyle: {
          backgroundColor: 'transparent',
        },
      }),
      initialRouteName: 'LandingPage',
    }
  )
);
export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <ImageBackground
        source={require('./bgimage.jpeg')}
        style={{
          flex: 1,
        }}>
        <RouterNavigator />
      </ImageBackground>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: But it is displaying Landing page text on background image in App.